# google.maps.MapTypeId button size for signed-in maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I change the size of map type switch button in API v3?

Left image shows Google Map API v3 and right image shows normal Google Map, I want to change the size of this button in API to roughly the same as in normal maps.

[image: Left image shows Google Map API v3 and right image shows normal Google Map]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems there is no API-option to modify the size of this control.

Currently this CSS would be a workaround:

```
  .gm-inset-container {
     width: 84px !important;
     height: 84px !important;

   }
   .gm-inset-map,
   .gm-inset-map-impl {
     width: 80px !important;
     height: 80px !important
   }
   .gmnoprint[controlheight="42"][controlwidth="42"] {
     bottom: 84px !important
   }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/ee3bbwn8/

Note: the overview-map inside the control will be offset when you use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The MapType control may appear in one of the following style options:

- google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR displays the array of
  controls as buttons in a horizontal bar as is shown on Google Maps.
- google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU displays a single
  button control allowing you to select the map type via a dropdown
  menu.
- google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT displays the "default"
  behavior, which depends on screen size and may change in future
  versions of the API

You read about it more [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#DefaultUI).

Comment: It's a [signed-in map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/signedin#changes_to_map_controls) , the options above doesn't apply to signed-in maps.

Comment: How did you know it was signed-in map?

Comment: the control you see in the left image will only appear on a `google.maps.Map` when it's a signed-in map